# git: Everything is up to date

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I upgraded my gitlab server host.  Once I finished installing the new system I changed my DNS settings and pointed the old domain to the new server.  Now when I try to push any projects it says:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

I've set a new origin, and ran the following:

```
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin https://---.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

But I still get the Everything up-to-date even though there are no files in the repository.

I'm fairly new to git and everything I've searched and tried doesn't seem to work.  I've tried forcing the push, reinitializing the repository but still nothing works.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you do not have any files added or modified.

Comment: Check inside the ".git" the configuration file I am not sure... I think it was called "config"  check that the URL is the new remote origin.

Comment: In rename remote, you need to pass new origin as the second argument.  ex:  git remote rename old-origin new-origin. try this. Also, confirm in .git/config file that remote have changed.

Answer (score 0):

From your surprise at "everything is up-to-date", I'm assuming you hadn't previously copied the git repositories across to the new Gitlab installation. Because if you had, everything *could* be up-to-date.

But if you haven't copied the repositories over to the new server, that logically means *they don't exist*. So I think you need to create them.

Comment: Makes sense, I have not copied the git repositories to the new installation but I did make the repository again when I tried this but I still get everything is up to date.

Comment: Do you have access rights to push to it? Does it recognise your old credentials?